# Laravel, ENV Variable from routes file

Tags: php, laravel

I try to access ENV variable from routes/web.php file, but it keep failing. The reason is I want to make special routes group for dashboard / client area. Here is my latest code;

```
$dashboard = env('DASHBOARD_DOMAIN', 'localhost');

Route::group(['domain' => 'dashboard.localhost.dev','middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'DashboardController@index');
});
```

Above code is work, but I don't want to hard code the domain value like that, because if I use this way I need to change them again everytime I upload my code to production server. But if I put $dashboard as domain value, it simply not work.

Comment: Here to let you know that if you upgrade your app to Laravel 5.3, the env function will work in the web.php file that replaces the routes.php file.

Answer (score 3):

The code should work properly if you define `DASHBOARD_DOMAIN` in `.env`.

```
Route::group([
      'domain' => 'dashboard' . env('DASHBOARD_DOMAIN', 'localhost') . 'dev',
      'middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'DashboardController@index');
});
```

Comment: Already do it but its just not work, I sure I put correct variable in .env because I test it in other file to return env('DASHBOARD_DOMAIN', 'localhost') and it work, but it can't work from route file

Comment: I can confirm this works in the latest version of Laravel, 5.3

Comment: this works in 5.5 as well but make sure to run `artisan config:clear` and then `artisan optimize` if you set new values.

Answer (score 1):

The env helper function is not available in the routes.php file. This is not possible.

Comment: It is now available in Laravel 5.3. I'm using the env function to pull a custom domain from the .env file. =]

Comment: Hmm, I tried in a L5.3 app and got ```null```. I ran ```php artisan config:cache ``` first, after updating a custom ```env()``` string. To test I added this to web.php   ```Route::get('/helper', function () {
         dd(env('DOES_HELPER_WORK'));
     }); ```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. But fixed by changing the function.

Change the variable like this.

```
config('dashboard.domain', 'localhost')
```

Clear cache by running

```
php artisan config:cache
```

**Your code will be like this.**

```
$dashboard = config('dashboard.domain', 'localhost');

Route::group(['domain' => 'dashboard.localhost.dev','middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'DashboardController@index');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a .env for your project and set your environment variables there.

So in your case:

'DASHBOARD_DOMAIN=localhost'

So in your routes file, you'd still use the 'env()' method, but now the value will be pulled from your .env file.

And just so you know, the second parameter if the 'env()' is the default, for when that variable hasn't been set elsewhere